# Confusion over real functions as a complex Fourier series

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am a bit confused with the following, I mean I do understand what these notes say, but does that mean that for real functions that the sum is only from 0 to  infinity rather than negative infinity to positive? Are terms doubling up? And do complex conjugates need to be taken?[image]

Answer (score 0):

He is just breaking 3.22 into two sums in the following way
$$
S(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2}\left(e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}+e^{\frac{-in\pi x}{l}} \right)+\frac{-ib_n}{2}\left(e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}-e^{\frac{-in\pi x}{l}} \right)
$$
$$
S(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{ib_n}{2}  \right)e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{ib_n}{2}  \right)e^{-\frac{in\pi x}{l}}.
$$
Now, on the right most sum let $n \to -n$ and you have
$$
S(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{ib_n}{2}  \right)e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \left(\frac{a_{-n}}{2}+\frac{ib_{-n}}{2}  \right)e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}.
$$
Here I think there is a typo in your book and the $c_n$ should be defined as follows
$$
\begin{cases}
c_0=\frac{a_0}{2}, \\
c_n=\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{ib_n}{2}, \ n>0,\\
c_n=\frac{a_{-n}}{2}-\frac{ib_{-n}}{2}, n<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that as he defined you would have to know the values $a_n, b_n$ for negative $n$ and in fact he defined $c_n$ in two different ways for positive values of $n$. Which makes no sense. But using the definition I give above notice that
$$
S(x)=c_0+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n  e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} c_n e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n  e^{\frac{in\pi x}{l}}.
$$